# Moving from dbo.sysobjects to sys.tables in sp_ procs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sysobjects

I used to write database-agnostic stored procedures by creating them in master with the `sp_` prefix and referring to dbo.sysobjects, which at runtime would bind to whatever database I happened to be in.

eventually I tried to migrate my code to use the newer, friendlier sys.tables, however, that binds to the database where the stored proc was compiled and thus returns the wrong data.

example:

```
use master
go
create proc sp_test
as
   select name
   from   sys.tables
go
use MyOtherDb
go
exec sp_test
go
```

will yield a list of the tables in `master` NOT in `MyOtherDb` - consequently when writing this stuff now I'm obligated to wrap my code in a string and execute it dynamically, which is particularly difficult once I'm already a layer or two deep in code that writes code.

anyone have a solution to this problem?  I'm sure I'm not the only guy out there that has bashed his head against this!

Answer (score 0):

ah!  I need to mark as a system object:

`exec sp_MS_marksystemobject 'sp_test'`